# How to Start an UiPath Robot from ServiceNow via REST API

Tags: rest, scripting, servicenow, uipath

How can I start UiPath Robot that is connected to UiPath Orchestrator?  I want to send REST API commands to the Orchestrator from ServiceNow Interface.

Answer (score 1):

First get your personal url of schema

`https://platform.uipath.com/[account_logical_name]/[service_instance_logical_name] ...`

Overall you need to request this to get the logical name: `https://platform.uipath.com/cloudrpa/api/getAccountsForUser`

Here are the steps to do so:

1. Run JavaScript code in the browser, which will give you the Code challenge and Code verifier.
2. Modify the `account.uipath.com` URL with Code challenge and send a request in the Browser itself. Which will ask you to authenticate with the credentials.
   You need to pass this URL in browser and the browser URL will give back the authorization code.
3. Then you need to send request to `https://account.uipath.com/oauth/token` with body.
4. There you will get the bearer token.
5. You need to get the logical name, so again a request for `https://platform.uipath.com/cloudrpa/api/getAccountsForUser` you will get the name.
6. With all these, try to send the request again.

When you need more help please have a look on several **links** as they show even better how to do this in e.g. Postman:

- https://forum.uipath.com/t/orchestrator-api-how-to-trigger-a-process/15471/18
- https://forum.uipath.com/t/start-a-job-in-orchestrator-via-the-api-in-community-edition/145363/3
- https://docs.uipath.com/orchestrator/reference/about-odata-and-references#consuming-cloud-api
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=417&v=a2YlQMylshU